# Merge the contents of 2 cells into another 3rd cell using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two cells lets say: A1 and A2

The content of each one of them is a string:

A1: Hallo

A2: World

My goal is to merge the contents of A1 and A2 in another cell e.g. A3 i.e. A3's content should be:

Hallo World

I would like to do this using a VBA macro and not only for strings as contents..

Thanks both of u for your answers!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although, as MasterMix says, this is most easily achieved by a formula, if you have a reason why VBA must be used then it depends on how you wish to specify the cells.

You could do this as a function:

```
Private Function addTwoCells(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String
    addTwoCells = rngA & rngB
End Function
```

All this does is replicate the (much faster) built-in Excel concatenate function though.

You could also do it in one of about a hundred ways in a procedure, here's one way that prompts the user for the ranges:

```
Private Sub addTwoCellsProc()
    Dim rngA As String
    Dim rngB As String
    Dim rngOutput As String
    Dim rngTest As Range

    Do
        rngA = InputBox("Please enter first cell address", "Cell A")
        rngA = Range(rngA).Cells(1, 1).Address
        Set rngTest = Intersect(Range(rngA).Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells)
    Loop Until Not rngTest Is Nothing

    Do
        rngB = InputBox("Please enter second cell address", "Cell B")
        rngB = Range(rngB).Cells(1, 1).Address
        Set rngTest = Intersect(Range(rngB), ActiveSheet.Cells)
    Loop Until Not rngTest Is Nothing

    Do
        rngOutput = InputBox("Please enter destination cell address", "Output cell")
        Set rngTest = Intersect(Range(rngOutput), ActiveSheet.Cells)
    Loop Until Not rngTest Is Nothing

    Range(rngOutput) = Range(rngA) & Range(rngB)
End Sub
```

You could also use predefined ranges and loop through them if you have multiple ranges to combine.  If you explain a bit more about the scenario then someone might provide more specific code.

Comment: hi, what is "built-in Excel concatenate function"? You mean `&`? thx

Answer (score 3):

I suggest either an Excel formula

```
=A1&A2
```

or a VBA macro

```
Range("A3").Cell.Value = Range("A1").Cell.Value & Range("A2").Cell.Value
```

Comment: `&` This is the correct answer. why are we writing code?

Answer (score 0):

This one is quicker, just select the cells and they are merged into the first cell.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : Concatenate Text
' Author    : Tim Bennett
' Date      : 11/6/2015
' Purpose   : Concatenate selected text into first column
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'Sub Concatenate_Formula(bConcat As Boolean, bOptions As Boolean)
Sub Concatenate()

Dim rSelected As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim sArgs As String
Dim bCol As Boolean
Dim bRow As Boolean

    'Set variables
    Set rOutput = ActiveCell
    bCol = False
    bRow = False

    On Error Resume Next

    'Use current selection
    Set rSelected = Selection

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Only run if cells were selected and cancel button was not pressed
    If Not rSelected Is Nothing Then
        sArgs = "" 'Create string of cell values
        firstcell = ""

        For Each c In rSelected.Cells
            If firstcell = "" Then firstcell = c.Address(bRow, bCol)
            sArgs = sArgs + c.Text + " " 'build string from cell text values

            c.Value = "" ' Clear out the cells taken from
        Next

        'Put the result in the first cell
        Range(firstcell).Value = sArgs



   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: isn't it better to use `&` instead of `+`?

Answer (score 0):

In a more general case, here's a macro which concatenates any number of cells (even non-adjacent blocks of cells) Note: I didn't include code which checks user's cancellation.

```
Sub G()

    Dim strFinal$
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Set rngSource = Application.InputBox("Select cells to merge", Type:=8)
    Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox("Select destination cell", Type:=8)
    For Each rngArea In rngSource
        For Each cell In rngArea
            strFinal = strFinal & cell.Value & " "
        Next
    Next
    strFinal = Left$(strFinal, Len(strFinal) - 1)
    rngTarget.Value = strFinal

End Sub
```