# Macro combining multiple cells into one, with values separated by a comma

Tags: vba, excel-2007

In a previous posted answer, [Combine multiple cells into one in excel with macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089756/combine-multiple-cells-into-one-in-excel-with-macro), the following macro was provided..which works great by the way!

However, I need to separate the cell values with a comma. I have tried inserting a comma between the quotes "," but this is not working. Can someone please guide me so the resulting cell will separate the values with a comma? Thank you!

```
Sub JoinCells()

Set xJoinRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight source cells to merge",     Type:=8)
xSource = 0
xSource = xJoinRange.Rows.Count
xType = "rows"
If xSource = 1 Then
xSource = xJoinRange.Columns.Count
xType = "columns"
End If
Set xDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight destination cell", Type:=8)
If xType = "rows" Then
temp = xJoinRange.Rows(1).Value
For i = 2 To xSource
    temp = temp & " " & xJoinRange.Rows(i).Value
Next i
Else
temp = xJoinRange.Columns(1).Value
For i = 2 To xSource
    temp = temp & " " & xJoinRange.Columns(i).Value
Next i
End If

xDestination.Value = temp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/860240-concatall-udf-by-tigeravatar.html

The first post shows how to use it, and the 8th post is the most recent version.

[EDIT]
Alternately, just change both instances of `& " " &` to be `& "," &`

Comment: I have tried changing this & " " & to be & "," &
but it does not work. Splits the value in 2, so that instead of 12345,23189 I get 123,452,318. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, they're numbers, and Excel is converting it to a complete number with standard comma separation for you.  You can either format xDestination as text with `xDestination.NumberFormat = "@"` or you can add an apostrophe in front of your resulting value like so: `xDestination.Value = "'" & temp`

Comment: Also, the link I provided contains a UDF that will perform as desired.  You may want to give it a try.

Comment: Hello TigerAvatar! Just wanted to let you know that this one worked...xDestination.Value = "'" & temp. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use to do this. It only works for a single column, but can be easily adapted to work for multiple columns if necessary.

```
Function CommaList(DataRange As Range, Optional Seperator As String = ",", Optional Quotes As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim iCellNum As Integer
    Dim sTemp As String

    If DataRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        CommaList = "Select a Single Column"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For iCellNum = 1 To DataRange.Cells.Count
        If Quotes Then
            sTemp = sTemp + "'" + DataRange.Cells(iCellNum, 1) + "'"
        Else
            sTemp = sTemp + DataRange.Cells(iCellNum, 1)
        End If
        If iCellNum < DataRange.Cells.Count Then
            sTemp = sTemp + Seperator
        End If
    Next iCellNum

    CommaList = sTemp

End Function
```